# vcredist_x86.exe can't be installed in container built from mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.14393.3506

Tags: docker-image, windows-update, windows-container

After KB4537764 upgrade, our container can't be launched in winserver 2016. 
I followed [MS support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t) to upgrade our base image to mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:10.0.14393.3506. But it turns out that vcredist_x86.exe can't be installed on it.
Our application depends on vcredist_x86.exe. How to install it in latest windows container?
[image]

Comment: Wrong registry key, 32-bit component registration is stored in HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/etc

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run the same install command on a new docker host with KB4537764 installed, vcredist_x86 can be installed.
If the docker host has no KB4537764 installed, this issue will happen.

Thanks Hans Passant. I should have used below command to check

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*|select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate|Format-Table;
```